# How to un-inherit CSS border property?

Tags: css, border

In  section, I have declared that all tables should have 1px black border. However, later on a need comes up wherein I can use only bottom border for one specific table.

I created a separate class (table.botborder) and put border:0px in it to remove inheritance but its not working. In browser, I see outside border around the table. Can someone please help here how to I remove this outside border?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.botborder table,th,td{
border:0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="botborder">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `table.botborder table` – you're looking for a `table` inside a `table.botborder` . this doesn't reflect your markup

Answer (score 0):

you're not using the CSS selectors correctly due to which the desired styles are not applying

```html
<style>
table,th,td{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}

.botborder, .botborder tr, .botborder tr th, .botborder tr td{
  border: 0;
}
.botborder tr td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="botborder">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: An explanation of anything here would be helpful. [answer]

Answer (score -1):

Please check your CSS selectors. This should fix the issue for now:

```css
<style>

   table, th, td{
     border: 1px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }

  .botborder, th, td{
     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
   }

</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).